# Trouble with placing and formatting dates in ggplot2 graph using chron

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, epoch, chron

I've been trying to add appropriate dates on the x-axis of my graph, but can't figure out how to do it in a sane way. What I want is pretty simple: a date at every January 1st in between the minimum and maximum of my data set.

I don't want to include the month - just '2008' or '2009' or whatever is fine. A great example would be this graph:

[example graph](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2012/03/outgoing-mail-diurnal-image.png)

Except I want the date on every year, rather than every other year.

I can't seem to figure this out. My dates are defined as days since 1/1/1970, and I've included a method `dateEPOCH_formatter` which converts the epoch format to a format using the chron package. I've figured out how to make a tick mark and date at the origin of the graph and every 365 days thereafter, but that's not quite the same thing.

Another minor problem is that, mysteriously, the line `chron(floor(y), out.format="mon year",origin.=epoch)` outputs a graph with axis markers like 'Mar 2008', but changing the line to `chron(floor(y), out.format="year",origin.=epoch)` doesn't give me a result like '2008' - it just results in the error:

```
Error in parse.format(format[1]) : unrecognized format year
Calls: print ... as.character.times -> format -> format.dates -> parse.format
Execution halted
```

Here's my code - thanks for the help.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(chron)
argv <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
mydata = read.csv(argv[1])
png(argv[2], height=300, width=470)


timeHMS_formatter <- function(x) {                  # Takes time in seconds from midnight, converts to HH:MM:SS
h <- floor(x/3600)
m <- floor(x %% 60)
s <- round(60*(x %% 1))                         # Round to nearest second
lab <- sprintf('%02d:%02d', h, m, s)        # Format the strings as HH:MM:SS
lab <- gsub('^00:', '', lab)                    # Remove leading 00: if present
lab <- gsub('^0', '', lab)                      # Remove leading 0 if present
}

dateEPOCH_formatter <- function (y){
epoch <- c(month=1,day=1,year=1970)
    chron(floor(y), out.format="mon year",origin.=epoch)
}

p=  ggplot() + 
coord_cartesian(xlim=c(min(mydata$day),max(mydata$day)), ylim=c(0,86400)) +         # displays data from first email through present
scale_color_hue() +
xlab("Date") +
ylab("Time of Day") +
scale_y_continuous(label=timeHMS_formatter, breaks=seq(0, 86400, 14400)) +              # adds tick marks every 4 hours
scale_x_continuous(label=dateEPOCH_formatter, breaks=seq(min(mydata$day), max(mydata$day), 365) ) +
ggtitle("Email Sending Times") +                                                        # adds graph title
theme( legend.position = "none", axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.3)) +
theme_bw() +
layer(
    data=mydata, 
    mapping=aes(x=mydata$day, y=mydata$seconds), 
    stat="identity", 
    stat_params=list(), 
    geom="point", 
    geom_params=list(alpha=5/8, size=2, color="#A9203E"),
    position=position_identity(),
)   

print(p)
dev.off()
```

Comment: This, and your previous question would improve if you included some example data (using `dput` or similar). I think it will be easier to use `scale_x_date` and `date_breaks` from the `scales` library that is associated with `ggplot2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will be much easier to use the built in function `scale_x_date` with `date_format` and `date_breaks` from the `scales` package. These should work with most `date` classes in `R`, such as `Date`, `chron`  etc

for  example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(chron)
library(scales)

# some example data 
days <- seq(as.Date('01-01-2000', format = '%d-%m-%Y'),
            as.Date('01-01-2010', format = '%d-%m-%Y'), by = 1)

days_chron <- as.chron(days)
mydata <- data.frame(day = days_chron, y = rnorm(length(days)))

# the plot
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=days, y= y)) + geom_point() + 
 scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('year'), labels = date_format('%Y'))
```

[image]

To show how intuitive and easy these function are, if you wanted Montth-year labels every 6 months - note that this requires a very wide plot or very small axis labels

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=days, y= y)) + geom_point() +
   scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('6 months'), labels = date_format('%b-%Y'))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. It took some playing with, but that helped a lot - thank you.